# How to initialize view controller of a container view with viper design pattern in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, viper-architecture

I want to initialize a view controller of a container view with VIPER design pattern and I tried to use `addChild()` function but it didn't work so anyone can help?

```
let homeVC = Storyboard.Main.viewController(HomeViewController.self)
    let homeConfigurator = HomeConfigurator()
    homeConfigurator.configure(HomeViewController: homeVC)
    let listVC = Storyboard.Main.viewController(ListViewController.self)
    let listConfigurator = ListConfigurator()
    listConfigurator.configure(ListViewController: listVC)
    homeVC.addChild(listVC)
    listVC.didMove(toParent: homeVC)
    let homeNavigationController = HomeNavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.Please share code!!

Comment: I have updated my question please take a look at it

Comment: I think you also need to add `listVC.view` as a subview to the viewcontroller you wish to show it in

Comment: it works but any other view in homeVC disappeared @ShawnFrank

Comment: @YosefElbosaty - make another view inside `HomeViewController` which will be the container for `ListViewController`. Position this container where you want the `ListViewController` to appear and give it the size you want. Add the `ListViewController` to this container view as a subview, not to `homeVC.view`